# LINQ Query result makes no sense

Tags: linq

I am running a simple LINQ query that connects to a view and returns all of the data with the id that I send in.

My simple query is:

```
 var data = db.ViewDataAlls.Where(x => x.guidRequirementId == guidRequirementId);
```

if I run this query in the database:

```
select * from viewDataAll where guidrequiremendid = '{Guid Id Sent In Here}'
```

I get 2 rows back, however the LINQ query is returning 2 rows, but the rows are a duplicate of the first row, not 2 unique rows.

Any ideas?

EDIT: if I run this LINQ Query:

```
List<string> nums = db.ViewDataAlls
                      .Where(x => x.guidRequirementId == guidRequirementId)
                      .Select(x=>x.strNumber).ToList();
```

I get the individual row numbers, but if I just try to pull the entire row I get a duplicate of the first row multiple times...

Comment: Is `x.guidRequirementId` of type `string`, or `object`? You could be involuntarily comparing by reference. Just my first thought.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to display the results in the failing version.

Comment: @Jon What code are you looking for?  I am just enumerating the results of my linq query to see that the result set is wrong, however when I copy the value of the linq query (the SQL code) and execute it in SQL Server I return the correct dataset.  Linq is seeing how many rows are returned and returning the first row that many times...

Comment: @EvanGWatkins: How are you "seeing" the result? Dumping it to a console? Looking in the debugger? Writing it out in ASP.NET? A short but complete console app demonstrating the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: I concur with @JonSkeet that the issue is likely in how you are consuming the LINQ results, not the LINQ query itself. Try running your same LINQ query in LINQPad (www.LinqPad.net) and see if you get the same results.

Comment: @Jim thanks for the advise, that worked looking at the results in LINQPad.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same problem.** I was ready to conclude that this was a bug in Linq-to-SQL. Direct SQL queries against the view worked, Linqpad queries worked, etc... but for some reason querying against a view sometimes (and not even very often mind you, but when I'd find a particular value that failed, it appeared to always do so) failed. I verified that **the query being passed by Linq to the SQL Server was correct** (from the SQLServer logs), so it appeared the results were being mangled when they were received by Linq. Querying directly against the view or accessing the contents of the view via a defined association gave the same bad results.

Realizing that **the problem lay on the receiving side of the query (after the results were passed back to Linq)**, I finally tracked it down to the way I had added the view to the dbml. Originally I had dragged the view onto the dbml designer surface, and added an association to the table I wanted to link it to, a basic one-to-many association (using an basic fkid == id relationship). However I couldn't access the view from the table in code. I discovered that I needed to add a primary key to the child (view), so I set the id property as the PK. This seemed to work until I got an unexpected exception when doing a .SingleOrDefault() against the view through the association. Knowing that it should be impossible for my data to have more that one hit for the property I was filtering with, I ran it through the debugger, and sure enough I was getting the right number of results (2 in my case), but the second result was just a copy of the first. The same thing the OP saw.

**The solution it turns out is to set all the fields of the view as part of the primary key** (in the dbml; I only had 3). Somehow, having the id field as the lone PK was not sufficient for Linq. Once I did this I had no further problems. (It may not be necessary to designate every field as part of the PK, so you may wish to experiment, but just the one id is insufficient apparently).

Note that I did have the view set as "not unique" in the dbml, which one would think would keep this from happening. Apparently not so.

Answer (score 0):

Is ViewDataAlls a view or a table. If it's a view, maybe the sql statement generating that view produces duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JHurdlow, you save my day. Looks like LINQ does not use the groupby or order-by in the views. In my case, the SQL Statement in the view was correct and data was presented very well, but for any reason when use LINQ on my MVC3 is different and duplicates rows. In my case I had  a view with 5 tables and I had to put all fields as PK on the view at `___DataModel.edmx`. Now works fine.

This solution implies that all fields must be not-null, otherwise has to use CASE NULL-THEN END on the View schema.